# Cannot animate SVG along path produced in Inkscape

Tags: animation, svg, inkscape

I have the following SVG produced in Inkscape, it has a Pacman figure (`id=pacman`) and a path (`id=trajectory`) . The objective is to make the figure move along the path.

[image: Vector graphics illustration of a yellow Pacman figure and a path]

After saving the image to a file, I edit it, by adding the following section within the Pacman-figure:

```
      <animateMotion
         path="m 39.645298,114.12279 c 24.797657,0.79422 33.02086,-32.601373 61.073142,-32.542731 27.55775,0.05761 37.28264,-38.721653 63.91959,-39.287919"
         begin="2s"
         dur="10s"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         rotate="auto" />
```

The path coordinates are copied from the `trajectory` object. As a result, I get this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="165.06496mm"
   height="104.70296mm"
   viewBox="0 0 165.06496 104.70296"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8"
   inkscape:version="0.92.3 (2405546, 2018-03-11)"
   sodipodi:docname="clean-animation.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="1.4"
     inkscape:cx="343.91864"
     inkscape:cy="205.09936"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1005"
     inkscape:window-x="-9"
     inkscape:window-y="1071"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-19.575883,-23.159755)">
    <path
       style="opacity:0.597;fill:#ffff00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#008000;stroke-width:0.26458332;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:0.26458331, 0.52916662999999997;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:0.8"
       id="pacman"
       sodipodi:type="arc"
       sodipodi:cx="33.408691"
       sodipodi:cy="115.25672"
       sodipodi:rx="13.698855"
       sodipodi:ry="12.473214"
       sodipodi:start="0"
       sodipodi:end="5.9207142"
       d="m 47.107547,115.25672 a 13.698855,12.473214 0 0 1 -12.459194,12.42204 13.698855,12.473214 0 0 1 -14.714154,-10.1738 13.698855,12.473214 0 0 1 9.796115,-14.26337 13.698855,12.473214 0 0 1 16.487129,7.59231 l -12.808752,4.42282 z"
       inkscape:label="#path815">
      <animateMotion
         path="m 39.645298,114.12279 c 24.797657,0.79422 33.02086,-32.601373 61.073142,-32.542731 27.55775,0.05761 37.28264,-38.721653 63.91959,-39.287919"
         begin="2s"
         dur="10s"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         rotate="auto" />
    </path>
    <path
       style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 39.645298,114.12279 c 24.797657,0.79422 33.02086,-32.601373 61.073142,-32.542731 27.55775,0.05761 37.28264,-38.721653 63.91959,-39.287919"
       id="trajectory"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="csc"
       inkscape:label="#path817" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

The problem is that the animation does not work. After 2 seconds, as defined by `begin="2s"`, the yellow figure simply disappears.

My first guess was that the coordinates are somehow offset, and the Pacman shape is animated somewhere in outer space. However, if that were the case, then I'd see the shape come back for a few moments at the beginning of each cycle.

When I experiment with handwritten SVGs found in various tutorials - they work. However, the ones I make in Inkscape myself do not behave as expected.

**What is the reason for this and how can this be corrected?**

Comment: You need to centre your pacman shape at the origin (0,0). Or you need to start your motion path at 0,0.  The offset of the pacman is added to the offset of the motion path position.  Meaning your pacman will be off the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand what happens please add `overflow:visible` to the svg element. You'll see that the packman is wondering far away from the path

In the next example I'm changing your packman for a circle. The path for the circle **is centered around the point {x:0,y:0}** You should rewrite the path for the packman so that it begins in the origin of the svg element.

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg width="165.06496mm"
   height="104.70296mm"
   viewBox="0 0 165.06496 104.70296"
   id="svg8">
  <g id="layer1" >
    <path
       style="opacity:0.597;fill:#ffff00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#008000;stroke-width:0.26458332;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:0.26458331, 0.52916662999999997;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:0.8"
       id="pacman"
       d="M-12.5,0A12.5 12.5 0 0 1 12.5,0A12.5 12.5 0 0 1 -12.5,0">
      <animateMotion
         path="m20.07, 90.96 c24.798, 0.794 33.021, -32.601 61.073, -32.543 c27.558, 0.058 37.283, -38.722 63.920, -39.288 1 27.55775,0.05761 37.28264,-38.721653 63.91959,-39.287919"
         begin="2s"
         dur="10s"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         rotate="auto" />
    </path>
    <path
       style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m20.07, 90.96 c24.798, 0.794 33.021, -32.601 61.073, -32.543 c27.558, 0.058 37.283, -38.722 63.920, -39.288 "
       id="trajectory" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Indeed, it was sufficient to set `sodipodi:cx="0" sodipodi:cy="0"` in the pacman shape of the original file. A thing is still not clear - if I edit the files using Inkscape and I have a complex picture with many moving elements that are supposed to move along paths - putting them all to `0,0` ruins the image itself. It looks good when the animations are live in a browser, but when editing the static image in Inkscape - the moving objects are not where they belong. Is this the best practice?

Comment: This is [a demo from the MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion#SVG) where the animated circle has no value for `cx` or `cy` this being equivalent to `cx="0" cy="0"`. If what bothers you is seeing the packman during the 2 seconds before the beginning of the animation you can change the viewBox of the SVG element so that the origin point `0,0` stays outside the canvas